# dataValues has to be present after model name to retrieve its value

Tags: sequelize.js

Here is code to retrieve of a ForTrade with join to Artwork and Viewer with sequelizeus 6.x:

```
let _bid = await ForTrade.findOne({
            where: {id:_id},
            include:[{
                model:Artwork,
                include: [{
                    model:Viewer,
                    attributes:[["wallet_address", "trader_address"]] 
                }]
            }]
        });
        console.log("_bid viewer in addressoftrader : ", _bid.artwork.viewer.dataValues.trader_address);  //this is the right format to retrieve trader_address
```

Here is the association of the model:

```
Artwork.belongsTo(Viewer, {foreignKey: 'uploader_id'});
  ForTrade.belongsTo(Artwork, {foreignKey: "artwork_id"});
```

`_bid.artwork.viewer.dataValues.trader_address` can retrieve the value of `trader_address` which is a string. But `_bid.artwork.viewer.trader_address` yields `undefined`. Why `dataValues` has to be added after viewer to retrieve viewer object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value that is returned from your findOne() query is not a plain object, it is a Sequelize instance.

This Sequelize instance can be manipulated using Sequelize methods such as set(), increment(), decrement(), and save(). Very useful.

As you've seen, you can access the dataValues property of this object, but I suspect that this is considered unsafe. You can, however, turn this instance into a plain object by invoking the .toJSON() method or the .get() method.

Slight tangent: One of the reasons this concept isn't immediately apparent is that when you use something like Express, you can simply use the res.json() method, pass in the _bid variable, and it will be sent to the client as a plain object. The reason for this is because the Express .json() method seeks out a .toJSON() method on an object passed into it. Because of that, it will send the plain object rather than the Sequelize instance.

Comment: Your post offers much more details about sequelizejs query result. For other query method, such as findByPk, findAll, do they all return instance of sequelize? By reading the doc, we know findByPk returns either null or obj and findAll return [] or an array. Or shall every query be .toJSON() before further use?

Comment: All of the query methods return instances. findAll() will return an array of instances. You will frequently need to map over arrays returned from findAll() to call on .get() or .toJSON() if you want to read those values server-side. I would recommend against viewing this as an annoyance, though. The utility methods available on the instances are extremely powerful and useful.

Comment: Before nodejs returns the instance of the model (return res.status.send(...)), is the instance converted to plain js object? It seems to be the case from the console output at the front end.

Comment: I can only say for certain that the expressJs .json() method invokes the .toJSON() method of the argument passed into it. If you're using Node servers out of the box and it's sending a plain object, I would assume that those Node methods do the same thing.